# How to execute a shell command through Grails application running in Tomcat7?

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, ubuntu-14.04

The following code works only in my dev environment. However, it throws an error in production (described below).

```
class ThemeBuilder {

  def compileTheme(basePath, courseID, desiredColor) {
    def outputCSSFilename = basePath + 'themes/' + courseID.toString() + '.css'
    def tmpFilename = basePath + courseID.toString() + '_tmp.scss'
    def sourceFilename = basePath + 'theme-builder-source.scss'

    def source = new File(sourceFilename)
    def tmp = new File(tmpFilename)

    def pattern = ~/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$/
    def matches = pattern.matcher(desiredColor).matches()

    // Checks existence of the path for themes
    def dir = new File(basePath + 'themes')
    if (! dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs()

    // Validate color
    if (!matches) desiredColor = '#4F9C91'

    // Replace placeholder color with desired color
    tmp.withWriter { w ->
      source.eachLine { line ->
        w << line.replaceAll('brand-primary: #F7DC40', 'brand-primary: ' + desiredColor) + System.getProperty('line.separator')
      }
    }

    // Compilation process
    def cmd = 'sass ' + tmpFilename + ' ' + outputCSSFilename + ' --style compact'
    def result = cmd.execute()
    result.waitFor()

    //////////////// Debugging ////////////////
    // println "Text output: ${ result.text }"
    // println "Return code: ${ result.exitValue() }"
    // println "stderr: ${ result.err.text }"
    // println "stdout: ${ result.in.text }"
    //////////////////////////////////////////

    // Remove tmp file
    tmp.delete()
  }

}
```

The error:

```
2014-10-22 14:41:28,886 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IOException occurred when processing request: [PUT] /pemaap/course/update
error=2, No such file or directory. Stacktrace follows:
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
        at br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.ThemeBuilder.compileTheme(ThemeBuilder.groovy:32)
```

Notice that the problem starts at line 32, which corresponds exactly with the line `def result = cmd.execute()`.

I could not check if the tomcat7 user (ps aux | grep tomcat) is capable to execute the sass, installed by root user OR if actually it's missing some mandatory file. Has anyone experienced this?

Obs: The server is running on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Comment: could you try with an absolute path for SASS?  also there are ways to use sass without the CLI tool (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894443/compile-sass-with-compass-in-ant-build-xml and Vaadin comes with SASS compiler (maybe not with all features))

Comment: @cfrick, your suggestion worked, but I ran into another problem. I couldn't disable caching for static files, even when cachingAllowed is set to "false" on every Context tag I found. Also, I removed every prior cached file, like in /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/Catalina/localhost and /var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost. Have you already faced it?